# Ansible - Create svn repositories if they do not exist

Tags: svn, ansible

How do I create a list of Subversion repositories (using `svnadmin create`) with Ansible only if they do not already exist?

Answer (score 4):

The key is to use the `creates` argument for the `command` module, which tells Ansible not to re-run the command if the given path exists. Here is an example playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  vars:
    - svn_repositories: ['test1', 'test2']
    - svn_data_dir: /var/svn
  tasks:
    - name: Create missing svn repositories
      command: "svnadmin create '{{svn_data_dir}}/{{item}}'"
      args:
        creates: "{{svn_data_dir}}/{{item}}/README.txt"
      with_items: "{{svn_repositories}}"
```